How to take a part of the shape that built by the curve?
I am a newbie in mathematica so I would like to ask any help for this probloem. I plotted this curve
Plot[1/515.56^21/((1 - (x/6.55)^2)^2 + (0.02x/6.55)^2), {x, 5.5,
7.5}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.01}].
Now I want to take the area that limitted by that curve, y=0, x= 0, and x=10, that erea is shadowed as the attached picture. Please show me how to do that. Thank you very much.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
